# "Собеседник печатает сообщение" Online Chat (Web)

Tags: ajax, php, online, javascript, mysql

Уважаемые #ХэшКодеры =) вот я столкнулся с ситуацией что сейчас у меня 21:46, и я не знаю чем себя занять, мне интересно как с помощью PHP / JavaScript / MySQL ну и т.п. реализовать функцию "Собеседник печатает сообщение".
На эту тему у меня только рассуждения делать ежесекундный запрос в базу данных, а у пользователя который печатает обновлять время в базе по функции

```
onKeyPress="press();"
```

Хотелось бы ваши предложения и советы по реализации данного функционала. Думаю будет интересно по дисскусировать с вами на эту тему.

Для примера добавил скриншот, я понимаю что "Mail.Ru Agent" это не WEB но просто что-бы вы поняли о чем я.

[image]

Comment: на сервере это лучше делать не на php, т.к. кучка активных long poll(или любых других ожидающих соединений) к php быстро скушает память.  тут надо использовать событийную модель http сервера.

Comment: @eicto это понятно, просто хотелось бы услышать мнение у тех кто с этим работал, и развести более менее интересный "Для меня" да и возможно не только вопрос, на более большую публику, что-бы пользователь в будущем имел представление как это сделать... Пока что ответ @fori1ton мне очень нравится, сижу копаю о Socket'ах и т.п =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ежесекундный запрос в базу очень быстро загрузит сервер. Чем больше пользователей, тем быстрее такое приложение упадёт. Для реализации подобного используют long polling: соединение с сервером держится открытым, при этом сервер может в любой момент посылать клиенту сообщения (например, о том, что другой пользователь печатает ему сообщение). Клиент же посылает данные на сервер отдельными AJAX-запросами. Такое можно реализовать либо попросту не закрывая соединение на сервере и дописывая туда сообщения по мере их поступления (старый добрый AJAX), либо с помощью WebSocket (HTML5 style).

Ссылки по теме: [раз](http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet/long-poll), [два](https://web.archive.org/web/20151026151945/http://habrahabr.ru:80/post/41223/), [три](http://www.nolithius.com/game-development/comet-long-polling-with-php-and-jquery), [четыре](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code).

Comment: "Два" ведёт на страницу "Доступ закрыт". Если вы ещё тут...

Comment: Интернет [помнит](https://web.archive.org/web/20151026151945/http://habrahabr.ru:80/post/41223/) всё) Впрочем, опираться на статью семилетней давности не самая лучшая идея

Comment: Спасибо, теперь открывается)

Answer (score 4):

Про PHP решения [@fori1ton](/users/5577/fori1ton) уже хорошо сказал, я же предлагаю NodeJS + SocketIO. Думаю, нагуглить информацию не составит труда. Что интересно - основному приложению (которое может быть и на PHP, и на чем-то еще) знать о NodeJS совершенно не обязательно. Как раз для случая "и я не знаю чем себя занять".