# Чат и общение

Tags: php, соцсети, javascript

Здравствуйте, дорогие ХешКодовцы, у меня к вам вопросы более драматические: "Что почитать"

В общем, тема, которую я затрагиваю, вполне большая и требует изучения. А именно:

1. Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно почитать общую теорию чатов, желательно связка php+javascript.
2. По поводу юзеров и уровней доступа (групп) я уже знаю, но не могу сообразить, как можно организовать хранение сообщений переписок на сервере (желательно тоже почитать).
3. А так же меня интересует организация множественных чатов между пользователями. То есть переписка конкретно между двумя пользователями (Например, как организовано ВКонтакте, сообщения в Майле и прочее), а так же создание конференций. Знаю, сложная тема, поэтому лучше что почитать.

Желательно, материалы на русском, но и английские источники тоже не помешают.

P.S. Я танцую с бубном и хочу попробовать начирикать свою простенькую социальную сеть (В качестве изучения, набора опыта). Поэтому такие вопросы.

Comment: 1. google php ajax
 2. база данных
 3. а тут я бы вообще от php отказался :)

Comment: 1. Гугл выбрасывает огромную коллекцию чайник-статей, и только единицы чего-то стоят.
2. На счёт БД согласен, но можно и файлы в случае php, или xml по средствам дома. Вопрос не о средстве, а о организации.
3. Я знаю. Вообще социалку лучше писать сервером, на плюсах или сишке, или удобном языке. Но хочется именно потанцевать с бубном, выжить из пыха всё, что можно.

Comment: Я тут как-то смотрел [несколько статеек][1] по теме [AMQP-PHP чат][2]. У самого руки не дошли опробовать, но может вам пригодится.
   
   [1]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/70757/
   [2]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/70997/

Comment: @Вовка Федосов, тогда [4][1]...

[1]: http://otvet.mail.ru/question/46738899

Comment: Deonis, спасибо за ссылочку, почитаем.

Zelta, летарический - (от слова летаргия) вопрос забвения, или вопрос, на который ответа найти не реально. Как-то так. Но он уже явно драматический. Всё-ровно, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: > официальные источники не в счёт
почему ? ну откуда такое желание и неприятие информации от тех кто это разрабатывал ? Кто кроме них знает точнее ?

Comment: Eicto, почему не в счёт? Ты не прав этими вопросами. Как раз в счёт. Но вот только официальная документация к тому же PHP огромна, и искать то, что конкретно надо - очень долго. Поэтому я и задал этот вопрос. Не в обиду, если он тебя немного обидел, я только учусь.

Comment: непонятно что вы хотите. выжимать асинхронный сервер из php, это всё равно что дейтерий из воды электролизом получать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вам нужно читать про сокеты. Архитектуру не подскажу, так как с php знаком не сильно. Но когда-то [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215402/php-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-online-chat-web) точно такое сообщение. Часто такие сервисы делают отдельным приложением: php отдает страничку, на соседнем порте какой-нибудь tornado или node.js раздает обновления информации. Но можно, наверное, и на чистом php, если чат будет [не очень большой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%F0%EE%E1%EB%E5%EC%E0_10000_%F1%EE%E5%E4%E8%ED%E5%ED%E8%E9). Вообще, выжимание из пыха последней капли ведет к нервным расстройствам. Каждой работе свой инструмент =)

Comment: А без сокетов такую задачу вообще не решить.

К сожалению, я не могу использовать tornado или node.js (хотя для решение этой задачи вещи очень хорошие), но решение должно не выходить за рамки php+mysql со стороны сервера.

Ладно, буду думать над тем, как это придумать, да и есть кое-какие уже идеи. Пожелайте мне удачи и не сойти с ума.

Comment: можно и без сокетов, тем более, если вы ограничены php.